# Deploy rails react app with webpacker gem on AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, webpacker

I'm trying to deploy a rails 5.1 & react app created with webpacker gem using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The problem is I keep getting the following error:

```
Webpacker requires Node.js >= 6.0.0 and you are using 4.6.0
```

I'm using Node 9.5.0 on my computer. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install nodejs using yum (assuming you're using the default Amazon Linux)

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -
yum -y install nodejs
```

Now to execute this on your instances, you need to add the required commands to a config file inside the `.ebextensions` dir, something like: `.ebextensions/01_install_dependencies.config`

File contents:

```
commands:
  01_download_nodejs:
    command: curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -
  02_install_nodejs:
    command: yum -y install nodejs
```

Comment: Question on this. I have the default `.elasticbeanstalk` folder is `.ebextensions` a completely different folder?

Comment: @SimonCooper yes, the `.elasticbeanstalk` folder contains configurations for your local eb CLI environment and other stuff

Comment: You also can ssh into the instance and execute those commands with sudo: type in the console **eb ssh**

Comment: @Borzh As stated when you log in via ssh to an eb instance: `Changes made via SSH WILL BE LOST if the instance is replaced by auto-scaling.`

Answer (score 5):

For those that run into needing to also install Yarn, I have found the below just worked for me:

```
commands:
  01_install_yarn:
    command: "sudo wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo && curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo bash - && sudo yum install yarn -y"
  02_download_nodejs:
    command: curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -
  03_install_nodejs:
    command: yum -y install nodejs
```

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who found this issue when upgrading to Rails 6, [I wrote a post](https://austingwalters.com/rails-6-on-elastic-beanstalk/) on how to fix it.

Basically, you have to:

- Create directory .ebextensions in the top level of your application
- Create .config file which contains the commands to fix deployments (script here)

  - Add commands for upgrading nodejs to >=6.14.4
  - Add container commands to install webpack & precompile assets
- Disable asset building through elastic beanstalk

  - set set RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION to True

What that amounts to is:

```
commands:

  01_install_yarn:
    command: "sudo wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo && curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo bash - && sudo yum install yarn -y"
  02_download_nodejs:
    command: curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -
  03_install_nodejs:
    command: yum -y install nodejs

container_commands:

  04_install_webpack:
    command: npm install --save-dev webpack
  05_precompile:
    command: bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: I get an error that says `error @rails/webpacker@4.2.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=8.16.0". Got "6.17.1"`.

I think the Rails Webpacker requires a version better than `8.16.0`. I updated the setup scripts (in your 01 and 02 steps) to use setup_13.x. Dunno why but the logs still tell me I'm using Node 6.x and 8.x+ is needed

Comment: Maybe add `command: "yum clean all"` to `03_install_nodejs:`?