# Deploying Rails 6.0 to AWS EB, Webpacker requires Node.js version error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I am attempting to upload a rails app that was recently updated from rails 5.2 to 6 to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. We had someone else working on this, but with the pandemic he had to step away - and now our site is kind of in limbo and I have not been able to update it. I have searched many different variations of my problem but no solutions have worked yet.

The app was working on EB with rails 5.2. I have the app running in 6.0 locally. When I **eb deploy** I get this error:

```
MacBook-Pro:app $ eb deploy
Starting environment deployment via CodeCommit
--- Waiting for Application Versions to be pre-processed ---
Finished processing application version app-0e294-200420_110159
2020-04-21 00:22:24    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2020-04-21 00:23:07    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2020-04-21 00:27:59    ERROR   [Instance: i-0e613ac1fe175f3f6] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...-- : Writing /var/app/ondeck/public/assets/application-06fe3df6175ba0def3d0e732489f883d0c09de.css.gz
Webpacker requires Node.js ">=10.13.0" and you are using v6.17.1
Please upgrade Node.js https://nodejs.org/en/download/
Exiting!. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2020-04-21 00:27:59    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2020-04-21 00:28:00    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0e613ac1fe175f3f6'. Aborting the operation.
2020-04-21 00:28:00    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.        

ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
```

It was giving me a bundler error before this, that I was able to fix by adding a file into **.ebextensions** that installs the correct version of bundler. I figured the solution to this would be similar.

This post was close to my problem: 
[Deploy rails react app with webpacker gem on AWS elastic beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798846/deploy-rails-react-app-with-webpacker-gem-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

So I added this file to my .ebextensions based off the selected answer of that:

**01_update_note.config**

```
commands:
  01_download_nodejs:
    command: curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -
  02_install_nodejs:
    command: yum -y install nodejs
```

However, it did not appear to do anything, I still get the same error. I tried a couple variations of the file based off a few other blog posts about the issue, but the error remains. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction or offer any insight into the problem? I apologize for not being very familiar with AWS or EB yet, but I will do my best to answer additional questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it is caused by `yarn install` later.
I try the following scripts and remove `yarn install` then set `RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION=false` and it works for me.

```
commands:
  01_install_yarn:
    command: "sudo wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo && curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash - && sudo yum install yarn -y"
  02_download_nodejs:
    command: curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -
  03_install_nodejs:
    command: yum -y install nodejs
  04_install_packages:
    command: sudo yum install -y yarn
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it on Amazon Linux 2:

Create this file in `.platform/hooks/prebuild/yarn_config.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo bash -
sudo yum -y install nodejs

sudo wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo
sudo yum -y install yarn

yarn install
```

Give it the right permission: `chmod +x .platform/hooks/prebuild/yarn_config.sh`

And the error is gone, while you assets still compile (unlike with accepted answer)

Answer (score 0):

The above answers install NodeJS from a deprecated path (`/setup_16.x`). This is now the latest way to do it for Amazon Linux 2 in `.platform/hooks/prebuild/yarn_config.sh`:

```bash
# Today, EB comes w/ node 16 already. Although if we don't install it like this, the yarn install below fails:
node_version=$(node --version | cut -c1-4)
echo "Current Node version: $(node --version)"
echo "Installing Node version 16:"
# Download code needed for node 16
sudo yum install https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_16.x/nodistro/repo/nodesource-release-nodistro-1.noarch.rpm -y
# Install node 16
sudo yum install nodejs -y --setopt=nodesource-nodejs.module_hotfixes=1
echo "Node installed. Version: $(node --version)"


# install yarn
yarn_version=$(yarn --version | cut -c1,2)
if [ "1." == "$yarn_version" ]; then
  echo "Yarn version 1.x.x already installed. No need to install."
else
  echo "Current Yarn version: $(yarn --version)"
  echo "Installing Yarn (not sure which version):"
  curl --silent --location https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo;
  yum -y install yarn;
  echo "Yarn installed. Version: $(yarn --version)"
fi
```

See also: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions